# declare and initialize 2d array with unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, constants

I take the size of rows n and columns m from the user

I want to make a 2D array (matrix) of the size nxm , initialize it and do some work on it

```
int main() 
{

int m,n;
cin>>m>>n;
const int grow=m;
const int gcol=n;
auto G = new double[grow][gcol](); //GIVES ERROR that grow and gcol must be const

/*int** G = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    G[i] = new int[n];*/
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can always index in a one dimensional array with `y * gcol + x` to make it effectively work as a two dimensional one. With that you can use a dynamic memory e.g. with a `std::vector<double>`.

Answer (score 1):

> //GIVES ERROR that grow and gcol must be const

No, it does not. Unless your compiler is bad. Read the error again.

It gives an error that `gcol` must be a constant expression.

You cannot have dynamic arrays of dynamic arrays. It's simply not possible in c++. You can only have dynamic arrays of things that have a static size, known at compile time.

Therefore, you cannot have a 2D array where both dimensions are determined at runtime.

You have 2 alternatives:

- Use a dynamic array of pointers to dynamic arrays. Which is what you have there, commented out. A dynamic array of vectors works too.
- Use a flat, one dimensional array that contains the rows in succession.

In either case, I recommend using a class to manage the memory. `std::vector`, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Array size is part of the type and needs to be known at compile time. You get it at runtime. Use vectors instead.